# erb:to:haml rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, haml, html2haml

I followed this screencast to make a erb:to:haml rake task:
http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/creating-a-rake-task-to-convert-erb-to-haml/

I backed everything up with git and then ran it, and it did the job beautifully, but now my pages aren't loading.

Here's the rake task from the screencast, my gemfile, the page in haml, the error, and also the output of 'bundle install' at the terminal.

I'm stumped for now.

--

Forgot gist earlier with errors :
https://gist.github.com/2820027

Comment: Did you forget to include “the rake task from the screencast, my gemfile, the page in haml, the error, and also the output of 'bundle install' at the terminal”?

Comment: I did... https://gist.github.com/2820027

Comment: What’s the `do` about on line 67 of `application.html.haml`?

Comment: @BuckDoyle, it was a method that hides a shopping cart if there's nothing in it. The indentation was all off. Now I see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Buck noticed, the line 67 does not contain valid HAML code:

```
  - if @cart
    = hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: 'cart') do
    = render @cart
```